# autocompletado de el calculo de dos input

Tags: javascript, html, funciones, function

en mi código tengo tres input de texto, que son peso, altura e IMC. Mi consulta es como puedo hacer que cuando se ingresen datos en peso y altura, en el input IMC me aparezca el resultado automáticamente, sin necesidad de botón.

PD: Fórmula de IMC: peso (kg) / [estatura (m)]2
PD2: tengo el script en un archivo diferente de js

```js
function calculoImc(){
  var peso = document.getElementById("peso").value;
  var talla = document.getElementById("talla").value;

  document.getElementById("imc").innerHTML = peso / Math.pow(talla,2);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" inputmode="numeric, decimal" id="peso" class="w-100" onkeypress="return valideKey(event);">

<input type="text" inputmode="numeric, decimal" id="talla" class="w-100" onkeypress="return valideKey(event);">

<input type="text" inputmode="numeric, decimal" id="imc" class="w-100" onkeyup="calculoImc()" onkeypress="return valideKey(event);">
```

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: Nada en verdad, no se me a ocurrido una forma de hacerlo sin que se tenga que hacer click en un boton para llevar a cabo el calculo

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer que cuando se escriba algo en uno de los inputs lo calcule el icm:

```js
function calculoImc(){
  var peso = document.getElementById("peso").value;
  var talla = document.getElementById("talla").value;

  document.getElementById("imc").value = peso / Math.pow(talla,2);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" inputmode="numeric, decimal" id="peso" class="w-100" onkeypress="calculoImc()">

<input type="text" inputmode="numeric, decimal" id="talla" class="w-100" onkeypress="calculoImc()">

<input type="text" inputmode="numeric, decimal" id="imc" class="w-100">
```

Lo malo de esto es que cuando solo haya un input escrito te saldrá escrito `NaN` (not a numer), esto lo puedes solucionar poniendo un if y utilizando la función `isNan()`